# How to convert a string into list of tuples in Python

Tags: python, string, list, type-conversion

I have strings in the following format and I am finding it difficult to convert these kind of strings into tuples -

```
text = '[(Apple Fruit, 10.88), (Table Top, 1.09), (Kicks, 1.08), (La Liga, 1.05), (Camp Nou, 1.02), (Football Team, 0.82), (, 0.73), (Hattrick, 0.7), (Free kick, 0.68), (Ballon dOr, 0.6), (, 0.53), (Treble, 0.51), (Vinegar, 0.09), (Ronaldo, 0.07)]'
```

I want to convert this string into list of tuples -

```
output = [('Apple Fruit', 10.88), ('Table Top', 1.09), ('Kicks', 1.08), ('La Liga', 1.05), ('Camp Nou', 1.02), ('Football Team', 0.82), ('', 0.73), ('Hattrick', 0.7), ('Free kick', 0.68), ('Ballon dOr', 0.6), ('', 0.53), ('Treble', 0.51), ('Vinegar', 0.09), ('Ronaldo', 0.07)]
```

I am not sure how to do. Can someone please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `convert` function which `splits` the *sequence* and *builds* the list of tuples.

```
text = '[(Apple Fruit, 10.88), (Table Top, 1.09), (Kicks, 1.08), (La Liga, 1.05), (Camp Nou, 1.02), (Football Team, 0.82), (, 0.73), (Hattrick, 0.7), (Free kick, 0.68), (Ballon dOr, 0.6), (, 0.53), (Treble, 0.51), (Vinegar, 0.09), (Ronaldo, 0.07)]'

text = text.replace("[","").replace("]","")

def is_digit(str):
   return str.lstrip('-').replace('.', '').isdigit()

def convert(in_str):
   result = []
   current_tuple = []
   for token in in_str.split(", "):
      chunk = token.replace("(","").replace(")", "")
      if is_digit(chunk):
         chunk = float(chunk)
      current_tuple.append(chunk)
      if ")" in token:
         result.append(tuple(current_tuple))
         current_tuple = []
   return result
```

Output

```
[('Apple Fruit', 10.88), ('Table Top', 1.09), ('Kicks', 1.08), ('La Liga', 1.05), ('Camp Nou', 1.02), ('Football Team', 0.82), ('', 0.73), ('Hattrick', 0.7), ('Free kick', 0.68), ('Ballon dOr', 0.6), ('', 0.53), ('Treble', 0.51), ('Vinegar', 0.09), ('Ronaldo', 0.07)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'\((.*?)\)')

text = '[(Apple Fruit, 10.88), (Table Top, 1.09), (Kicks, 1.08), (La Liga, 1.05), (Camp Nou, 1.02), (Football Team, 0.82), (, 0.73), (Hattrick, 0.7), (Free kick, 0.68), (Ballon dOr, 0.6), (, 0.53), (Treble, 0.51), (Vinegar, 0.09), (Ronaldo, 0.07)]'

pairs = regex.findall(text)

list_of_tuples = [tuple(p.split(',')) for p in pairs]

print(list_of_tuples)
```

1. First we import the regex module.
2. Define the regex pattern to look for: Anything between two parentheses
3. Search for that pattern in our `text` variable and return all matches.
4. Create a list of tuples using list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import ast
text = '[(Apple Fruit, 10.88), (Table Top, 1.09), (Kicks, 1.08), (La Liga, 1.05), (Camp Nou, 1.02), (Football Team, 0.82), (, 0.73), (Hattrick, 0.7), (Free kick, 0.68), (Ballon dOr, 0.6), (, 0.53), (Treble, 0.51), (Vinegar, 0.09), (Ronaldo, 0.07)]'

comma_added = True

for char in text:
    if char == '(' and comma_added:
        new_text+='("'
        comma_added = False
        continue
    if char == ',' and not comma_added:
        new_text+='"'
        comma_added = True
    new_text += char
print(ast.literal_eval(new_text))
```

Output:

```
[('Apple Fruit', 10.88),
 ('Table Top', 1.09),
 ('Kicks', 1.08),
 ('La Liga', 1.05),
 ('Camp Nou', 1.02),
 ('Football Team', 0.82),
 ('', 0.73),
 ('Hattrick', 0.7),
 ('Free kick', 0.68),
 ('Ballon dOr', 0.6),
 ('', 0.53),
 ('Treble', 0.51),
 ('Vinegar', 0.09),
 ('Ronaldo', 0.07)]
```

Or (very ugly!!!):

```
new_text = text.replace('), ','},').replace('(','("').replace(', ','", ').replace('},','), ')
print(ast.literal_eval(new_text))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex --> `Lookbehind & Lookahead`.

**Ex:**

```
import re
import ast

text = '[(Apple Fruit, 10.88), (Table Top, 1.09), (Kicks, 1.08), (La Liga, 1.05), (Camp Nou, 1.02), (Football Team, 0.82), (, 0.73), (Hattrick, 0.7), (Free kick, 0.68), (Ballon dOr, 0.6), (, 0.53), (Treble, 0.51), (Vinegar, 0.09), (Ronaldo, 0.07)]'
text = re.sub(r"(?<=\()([A-Za-z\s]+)", r'"\1"', text) #Convert letters to string
text = re.sub(r"(?<=\()(?=,)", r'""', text)           #Replace empty space with empty string.        
print(ast.literal_eval(text))
```

**Output:**

```
[('Apple Fruit', 10.88),
 ('Table Top', 1.09),
 ('Kicks', 1.08),
 ('La Liga', 1.05),
 ('Camp Nou', 1.02),
 ('Football Team', 0.82),
 ('', 0.73),
 ('Hattrick', 0.7),
 ('Free kick', 0.68),
 ('Ballon dOr', 0.6),
 ('', 0.53),
 ('Treble', 0.51),
 ('Vinegar', 0.09),
 ('Ronaldo', 0.07)]
```